# How to export books from Ibooks when using iCloud Drive

Tags: icloud, books

Aloha,

I would like to turn off iCloud Drive.
But I activated in iBooks iCloud Drive.
Now I don't see any "official way" to export all MY books out of iCloud drive.

The only way I currently found is to use terminal and make a

```
cp ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/ibooks~apple~com/ ~/Documents/MYbooks/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always drag-and-drop your .epub and .pdf files from iBooks.app onto your Desktop or any other folder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @oa-, I was just to stupid to see this obvious Apple like solution! Many thanks Marcel